# Time efficency when finding shortest way between nodes, python

Tags: performance, python-3.x, time, graph, nodes

The task is to calculate how many steps there are between two nodes in a k-ary tree. The tree will have N nodes and the maximum possible number of children will be K.
Q is the number of queries that will be asked, each one consisting of x and y, the nodes that you should find the way between.
I believe my code does this, the problem is that it takes too long. Any suggestions on how to make it more time efficent?
The code is as follows:

```
from sys import stdin, stdout

def check(xy, lista):
    while xy > 1:
        if (xy-1) % K == 0:
            j = ((xy-1)/K) - 1 
        else:
            j = (xy - 1)// K
        lista.append(int(j)+1)
        xy = j+1

    return set(lista)

N, K, Q = stdin.readline().split(' ')
K = int(K)
Q = int(Q)

while Q > 0:
    x, y = stdin.readline().split(' ')

    if K == 1:
        stdout.write(str(abs(int(x)-int(y))) + '\n')
    else:
        listx,listy = [int(x)],[int(y)]
        listx = check(int(x),listx)
        listy = check(int(y),listy)

        a = listy & listx
        merged = listy|listx
        stdout.write(str(len(merged)-len(a)) + '\n')

    Q -=1
```